# RedBeanPHP 4 __HALT_COMPILER();

Tags: php, redbean

Using this little script :

```
<?php
    require 'rb.phar';
?>
```

I get this error :

```
*PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message '__HALT_COMPILER(); must be declared in a phar' in /home/site1/rb.phar:8\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/site1/rb.phar(8): Phar::webPhar(NULL, 'index.php')\n#1 /home/site1/index.php(2): require('/home/site1/rb....')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /home/site1/rb.phar on line 8*

php -v :

PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u8 (cli) (built: Feb 17 2014 09:18:47)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
with XCache v2.0.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2012, by mOo
with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

uname -a :

Linux lamp 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone help me get this working, please? I downloaded the latest RedBeanPHP 4 from the website today.

**EDIT** - as answered by Gabor, removing xcache did get rid of the problem. Here's what I had to do :

```
mv /etc/apache2/conf.d/20-xcache.ini /etc/apache2/conf.d/20-xcache.ini.disabled
service apache2 restart
```

If anyone has a better way to disable it (or any other suggestions) please leave a comment.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you format it like that? The php -v output, I mean?

Comment: Could the down-voter please add a comment so I can understand why. Seems a perfectly valid question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be connected to an issue in XCache:

http://xcache.lighttpd.net/ticket/273

Comment: Yes this worked, thanks. The article (in the comments) suggests that V2 of xcache fixes the issue, but I'm on V2 and it remains.